# How to add file extension in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports

I have integrated the JasperReports library in Netbeans 7.0.1 by using Library Manager wizard. now i want to define a template file extension .jrxml .In a tutorial i read that this can be done by Advanced options that is under tools>options dialogbox.but in ide 7.0.1, their is no advanced options in options dialog box.can any one help?

Answer (score 3):

This is done in

```
Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Files
```

[image]